# Installation Issue for MongoDB GORM plugin on Grails 3.4.0

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin

My project is working fine. After I tried installing MongoDB plugin via Open grails plugin manager in GGTS IDE.

Now I am getting following error after running my project. 
Some info-- My MongoDB current version is v2.4.8. and I am installing this plugin.http://grails.org/plugin/mongodb.

```
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core
Configuring Spring Security Facebook ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Facebook
2014-01-22 01:28:16,788 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  hibernate.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory  - Couldn't find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [com.lyfe.sec.Authority]; using defaults.
| Error 2014-01-22 01:28:18,524 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Database name must only contain letters, numbers, underscores and dashes!
Message: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Database name must only contain letters, numbers, underscores and dashes!
   Line | Method
->> 109 | postProcessBeanFactory in org.grails.datastore.gorm.plugin.support.PersistenceContextInterceptorAggregator
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   303 | innerRun               in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   895 | runTask                in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
^   695 | run                    in java.lang.Thread
**Caused by IllegalArgumentException: Database name must only contain letters, numbers, underscores and dashes!**
->> 253 | createMongoTemplate    in org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.MongoDatastore
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   222 | afterPropertiesSet     in     ''
|    53 | getObject . . . . . .  in org.grails.datastore.gorm.mongo.bean.factory.MongoDatastoreFactoryBean
|   109 | postProcessBeanFactory in org.grails.datastore.gorm.plugin.support.PersistenceContextInterceptorAggregator
|   303 | innerRun . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run                    in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   895 | runTask . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run                    in     ''
^   695 | run . . . . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: is your mongod running with --auth? Sometime the grails error message are not very intuitive or display totally wrong message for a different error.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, i think you would say Grails 2.4.0. Ok Here is my DataSource.groovy for mongodb:

```
environments {
    development {
    grails {
        mongo {
            host = "10.0.11.243"
            port = 27017
            username = "username"
            password = "userpassword"
            databaseName = "yourdb"
            options {
                autoConnectRetry = true
                connectTimeout = 300
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

You must create a DB in mongo and a user that can access to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried creating the user and added below code in DataConfig.groovy

Answer (score 0):

What name have you used for the database?  Note the following line from the error:

```
Message: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': 
FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Database name** must only contain letters, numbers, underscores and dashes!
```

Somewhere in the config you've either entered an invalid database name or not set one at all.  Check the values in DataSource.groovy.